# "\renewcommand{\tilde}{\widetilde}" doesn't take affect in ctexbook class

Tags: renewcommand, ctex

I want to redeifne `\tilde` to `\widetilde`. However, it doesn't take affect.

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\renewcommand{\tilde}{\widetilde}
\begin{document}    
    $\tilde{A}\widetilde{A}$    
\end{document}
```

What's the problem?

Update: It seems that pdflatex does it correctly, however, for xelatex, I have to put `\renewcommand{\tilde}{\widetilde}` below `\begin{document}`, namely, the following code works fine.

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tilde}{\widetilde}   
    $\tilde{A}\widetilde{A}$    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @egreg  I'm using xelatex.  It seems that pdflatex works fine, but xelatex doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use XeLaTeX, `ctexbook` will load `fontspec` and this requires delaying some settings.

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\tilde}{\widetilde}}

\begin{document}

$\tilde{A}\widetilde{A}$

\end{document}
```

I'd not do it, to be honest, and use `\widetilde` only when necessary (which it isn't for a single letter).

Comment: Thank you. I just want to define a macro, which uses tilde for lower cases, and uses widetilde for upper cases.